# NodeJS: How to use html form to send PATCH & DELETE request

Tags: html, node.js

I have an API and i should send PATCH request if i need to update the object; the problem is that when i send the PATCH request the body is always undefined.

this how i send PATCH request Ex.

```js
app.patch('/applications/update/:application_id', function(request, response) {
    var application_id = request.params.application_id;

    require('../../models/applications/update_application_by_id')
        .get(request.body, application_id, function(result) {
            response.render('applications/details', {
                application_details:result
            });
        });
});
```

```html
<form enctype="application/json" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="/applications/update/{{application_details._id}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH" /> 
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-yellow pull-right">update</button>
</form>
```

and this how i handle it

```js
exports.get = function(request_body, application_id, call_back){
    var http_request = unirest("patch", "https://xx/api/applications/"+application_id);

    http_request.headers({
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "x-application-key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    });

    http_request.type("json");
    http_request.send(request_body);

    http_request.end(function (http_response) {
        console.log(http_request.body);
        if (http_response.error) throw new Error(http_response.error);

        return call_back(http_response.body);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so here we go,

i solve the problem by very easy way, since i'm talking with API so i have models files that talk with API so i defined my method on these files and make all the form as post and pass the post body as parmeter to models.

the example will explain more.

Model File:

```js
var request = require("request");

exports.get = function(request_body, application_id, call_back) {
    var options = {
        method: 'PATCH',
        url: 'http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'+ application_id,
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'x-application-key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        },
        body: request_body,
        json: true
    };
    
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);

        return call_back(body);
    });
};
```

Controller File:

```js
app.post('/applications/update/:application_id', function(request, response) {
    require('../../models/XXX/XXXX')
        .get(request.body, request.params.application_id, function(result) {
            response.render('XXXXX/details', {
                response_update:result
            });
        });
    });
```

Form Template:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="/applications/update/{{application.[0]._id}}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{application.[0].name}}" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-yellow pull-right">update</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're best off installing and app.use()ing the middleware express/methodoverride:

https://github.com/expressjs/method-override/blob/master/README.md

Pretty standard approach, but note the actual field names it will expect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to unwrap the request yourself.

You form is actually sending a normal POST request:

```
<form enctype="application/json" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="/applications/update/{{application_details._id}}">
```

So you need a route or middleware that converts that POST into a PATCH/DELETE, `_method` is.

Comment: i already add <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH" /> 
inside the form and still not work

Comment: It would not work if you don't explicitly handle on you on. ExpressJS **does not** do this for you.