# Express.js submit button routing getting wrong

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I'm trying to make an excercise, a simple "to-do list" with all of html requests. They all works fine except for the PATCH witch should redirect to "/" when actually goes to "/posts/2" and I get the "Cannot POST /posts/2" message and the array's element doesn't change.

I'm expecting it redirect to the home "/" and show all elements with the one I modified and I don't get where is the error. Here is the code:
INDEX.JS

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';


const app = express();
const port = 3000;

let todoList = [
    {
        id: 1,
        content: "Chase flogging pressgang aye overhaul dead men tell no tales mutiny lee Pieces of Eight draught.",    
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        content: "Barque trysail gunwalls yo-ho-ho scurvy gangway Blimey Davy Jones' Locker bounty weigh anchor.",
    },
];
let done = [];
var id = 2;
var data = {
    todo: todoList,
    done: done,
};

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : true }));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('GET');
    res.render('index.ejs', data);
});
//GET a specific post by id
app.get('/posts/:id', (req, res) => {
    if(todoList.length>0){
        let pId = parseInt(req.params.id);
        const post = todoList.find(i => i.id === pId);
        if(post){
            res.render('post.ejs', { post: post});
        }else {
            res.send('<h2>Post not found: <a href="/">Torna a Home Page</a></h2>');
        }
    } else {
        res.send('<h2>Array vuoto: <a href="/">Torna a Home Page</a><h2>');
    }
});

app.get('/edit/:id', (req, res) => {
    try {
        let pId = parseInt(req.params.id);
        const post = todoList.find(i => i.id === pId);
        //console.log(`id: ${post.id}, post: ${post.content}`);
        if(!post) res.status(404).json({ message: "Error fetching post." });
        res.render("edit.ejs", {todo: post});
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Error fetching post." });
    }
});
//POST a new post
app.post('/posts', (req, res) => {
    if(req.body.post ){
        const newId = id += 1;
        const newTodo = {
            id: newId,
            content: req.body.post
        };
    //console.log(newTodo)    
    todoList.push(newTodo);
    }
   //res.render('index.ejs', data);
   res.redirect("/");
});

//PATCH a post when you just want to update one parameter
app.patch('/posts/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log("PATCH");
    const pId = parseInt(req.params.id);
    console.log("pId: " + pId);
    const post = todoList.find((todo) => todo.id === pId);
    console.log("post.id: " + post.id);
    if(!post) res.status(404).json({message: 'Item not found'});
    
    //console.log("Post: " + post);

    const replacementPost = {
        id: pId,
        content: req.body.content || post.content,
    };    
    const postIndex = todoList.findIndex((todo) => todo.id === pId);
    if (postIndex > -1){
        //console.log(`Index: ${postIndex}`);
        todoList[postIndex] = replacementPost;
        //console.log(todoList);
        console.log("Updated: " + todoList[postIndex]);
        res.redirect("/");
    } else {
        res.send("No post content found");
    }
});
```

INDEX.EJS

```
<%- include('partials/header.ejs') %>
<% 
function excrept(text) { //Create a short text for post
    let shortTxt = text;
    let maxLength = 35;
    if (shortTxt.length > maxLength) {
        shortTxt = text.slice(0, maxLength) + "...";
    }

    return shortTxt;
}
%>
<h1>To Do List</h1>
<form action="/posts" method="POST">
    <textarea id="text" name="post" placeholder="Write your post" rows="5" autofocus required> </textarea><input type="submit" value="insert post"> 
</form>
    <div class="todo">
        <% if(locals.todo && todo.length > 0) {%>
        <form name="checked" method="post">
        <h2 id="todoList"> To do</h2>
        <% todo.forEach(element => { %>
            <div class="checklist-item">
                <input type="checkbox" id="<%= element.id %>" name="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="post-<%= element.id %>"  ">
                <label for="post-<%= element.id %>"><a href="/posts/<%= element.id %>"><%= excrept(element.content) %></a></label> <a class="edit" href="/edit/<%= element.id %>">Edit</a>
                <br>
            </div>
        </form>
        <% }); %>
    </div>
<% } %>
<%- include('partials/footer.ejs') %>
```

EDIT.EJS

```
<%- include('partials/header.ejs') %>

<h1>Modify Post</h1>
<% if(locals.todo) { %>
<form id="editTodo" action="/posts/<%= todo.id %>" method="post">
    <textarea name="content" id="txtcontent" rows="5"><%= todo.content %></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="modify">Modify</button>
</form>
<% } %>
<%- include('partials/footer.ejs') %>
```

Comment: I don't think you can send a PATCH request using an HTML form. Use JS to send the request instead, and make sure the method is PATCH in the request headers. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112722/nodejs-how-to-use-html-form-to-send-patch-delete-request

Comment: You can only do a GET or POST request from an HTML form. The server expects a PATCH request on the `/posts/:id`. Either rewrite the server so that it takes the POST request to that URL (the simplest solution) or create some JavaScript that can do the PATCH request.

Comment: Thank you all! @chrwahl if you look at my EDIT.EJS code, the **form method is POST** `<form id="editTodo" action="/posts/<%= todo.id %>" method="post">`. Like I saw on an online lesson, with the submit button I send the data to the server and I handle they with the `/posts/:id` end-point of the app.PATCH method. I thought it would work fine, since it was quite similar to the lesson's code.  Ah, I tested the code with Postman and there I can change the target ID post, the problem is when on the page I click the submit button. It doesn't trigger even the `console.log("PATCH")` inside.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
I changed `app.patch` to `app.post` and it works.